# How to filter data of least 6 month in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get user data of the last 6 months from the current date in MongoDB. I am filtering data by status than getting the array in response. I also want to apply another query on same based on date. I want to filter it once based on last 6 months then in another query based on last 30 days from current date.
My data is -

```
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63ac23187dc7d"),
    details: 'hii there i am feeling great today',
    status: '1',
    createdAt: 2021-11-28T11:06:00.736Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63ac23b357dc96"),
    details: 'hi i am feeling good today',
    status: '1',
    createdAt: 2022-12-28T11:08:40.400Z,
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63b2b2afa0d8e"),
    details: 'Hello!! This is Ankit and feeling good',
    status: '1',
    createdAt: 2022-11-14T10:31:36.098Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63b2b2sswa0d91"),
    details: 'Felling bad a bit',
    status: '1',
    createdAt: 2023-01-02T10:32:27.149Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63b2b2a0d94"),
    details: 'Hmm, its ok ok',
    status: '1',
    createdAt: 2023-01-02T10:33:19.386Z
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the $gte query operator and JavaScript's Date.now() function to retrieve all order documents with a date greater than or equal to 6 months before the current date. We will use new Date() of JavaScript to get the current date and the setMonth() method to go back 6 months.

You can try this

```js
let sixMonths = new Date();
sixMonths.setMonth(sixMonths.getMonth() - 6);

db.collections.find({ createdAt: { $gte: sixMonths } });
```

For the days, you can put "1"instead of "6" which is equivalent to 1 month.

Comment: How i will filter the date if I want between specific dated or years like show only data added in 2022 or 2023. I am using `$gt` and `$lt` but not getting output.

Comment: You can use $gte to retrieve dates greater than 2022 and $lt for dates less than 2023